# Product List Position in Google Analytics Event Table

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I want to analyze the Product List Position in Google Analytics Event Table. However, during the installation, our Technical Team made a mistake in product list position. Some items' position starts from 0. How to fix this problem with sql? I want to fix only the starting 0 position's list.

Best.

[image: Item Index Example]

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "fix"? What should the fixed result look like?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your issue, but you might insert data to the table and then remove specified rows with `0`.

For example:

[image]

```
insert into 'project-name.dataset.table' (select col1, (items.coupom, items.affiliation, items.refund) from 'project-name.dataset.table' where items.refund is null  );
```

It will looks like below:

[image]

And then delete unneeded rows

```
delete from 'project-name.dataset.table' where items.refund is null;
```

Result will be like below:

[image]

**Please note** that this may process a lot of data and you will have to insert the missing data in the last field that was affected by the error.